# custom == for Dictionary extension thinks they're empty

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, operator-keyword

I have an (enum : int) AccessOptions, which is used to populate a Dictionary to reflect simple access properties for an indexed list of user principal names.

I needed to support unit testing - specifically

```
    Assert.AreEqual
    <Dictionary<string, AccessOptions>, 
    Dictionary<string, AccessOptions>)
```

...which is messy, and invokes the Dictionary generic's equality operator that really only checks reference values -- what I need is to establish that two distinct reference objects contain the same keys by value, and that those keys' associated values match in each case.

So, I wrote my own equality operator, and created a class that extends Dictionary to avoid screwing up Dictionary objects in my project.  When this method is executed in Visual Studio 2016 in the context of debugging a unit test's Assert.AreEqual call, a couple of things go sideways, and I'll mark them below using comments.

```
        public class SecretAccessRuleSet : Dictionary<string, AccessOptions>
{
    public SecretAccessRuleSet() {}

    public SecretAccessRuleSet(int size) : base (size) {}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((SecretAccessRuleSet) obj);
    }

    public static bool operator == (SecretAccessRuleSet a, SecretAccessRuleSet b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, b))  
        { 
            return true; 
        }

        /* When the below statement executes in debug, I can watch 
         * execution flow from the equality test against (object)a,
         * straight to "return false" -- but execution does not actually
         * return, but appears to jump directly to the foreach statement
         * two blocks down.  It might be important, or just a bug.  
         */
        if (((object)a == null) || ((object)b == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (a.Count != b.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }

        /* Then when we get here, the visualizer highlights a; I advance 
         * one line and it highlights "in", which I assume is wherein an 
         * enumerator is initialized; I advance again and we jump to the 
         * end of the method!  Literally to the end curly brace.  
         */
        foreach (var entry in a)
        {
            AccessOptions bOpt;
            if (!b.TryGetValue(entry.Key, out bOpt)
                || bOpt != entry.Value)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If we get here, they're equal
        return true;
    }

    public bool Equals(SecretAccessRuleSet other)
    {
        return this == other;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(SecretAccessRuleSet a, SecretAccessRuleSet b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The test results indicate that the Assert.AreEqual(a, b) call returned false, but I have very low faith that the contents of either collection were evaluated, and I don't understand why.

I'll probably remove all of this and create a separate way to test these without overriding an operator, but -- what went wrong here?

(Thanks everyone, for your time.)

**Update:**  To specify the stuff I forgot, both collections are the expected type, non-null, and both contain 2 entries -- the same 2 entries, actually; I expected the equality operator to return true in the test.

**Update 2:**  I separated the null checks; "(object) a == null" evaluates to false, and continues, but "(object) b == null" appears to evaluate to true and send execution to "return false" -- but again, the same two problems where execution doesn't actually return but tries to enumerate a first... and b isn't actually null.  Are there reasons b would be a valid object but the cast operation in (object) b might fail?

Comment: While debugging you can mouse over `a` and see the contents. If it is empty, that's your issue.

Comment: As nhouser9 said, check if they are empty. Seeing how your (object)a goes straight to "return false", it might be that it's null and doesn't iterate.

Comment: See update -- sorry I didn't specify.  Both collections are of the expected type, not null, and have 2 entries each.  (As it happens, they match.)

Comment: You should also show your test code...

Comment: How is `!=` implemented for `AccessOptions`?

Comment: Have you considered `CollectionAssert.AreEqual`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243763.aspx

Comment: @Eris:  "Two collections are equal if they have the same elements in the same order and quantity."  That doesn't work for dictionary comparison, because dictionaries have no stable order.

Comment: Fine, CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent: Two collections are equivalent if they have the same elements in the same quantity, but in any order. Then only the key and value types would need to implement equality.

Answer (score 2):

What about this for your equality check?
After checking reference equality, nulls, and the number of keys, you can use `Except` to see if one contains keys not in the other. If it does they're not equal.

Only if all of those pass do you have to see if there are any cases where the values for the same keys in both dictionaries don't match.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    var other = obj as SecretAccessRuleSet;
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (Count != other.Count) return false;
    if (Keys.Except(other.Keys).Any()) return false;
    return Keys.All(k => string.Equals(this[k], other[k]));
}
```

Comment: I'd have to test the values in both Dictionaries as well.  The whole idea is to create the collections by two methods and validate that the results of both are identical.  I hadn't thought of using Except though. :)

Comment: That's what the last check does.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, as usual, simpler than I made it.

Dictionary object comparers are not explicitly case-insensitive, and there was a case mismatch in key creation between the two methods.  Redefining SecretAccessRuleSet constructors to call the base constructor with StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase fixed the issue.

The debug-focus-jumping issue is a display bug known to afflict unit tests in this context; the code wasn't really executing the highlighted lines.  That made the whole thing look way more bizarre than it really was.

Lessons learned:

- Post *all* the code involved (someone would have caught the case issue, but I assumed the details of the creation routes were out of scope for the issue, and I shouldn't do that).
- Blame plugins before suspecting the core IDE -- the testing they underwent was not equal.

Thanks everyone.